# Thin client "Error: Socket failed: Connection timed out" when booting from Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS LTSP server in virtual environment

Tags: 14.04, ltsp, ltsp-client

Trying to get a thin client to boot from my VirtualBox installed with `14.04.2` and `LTSP`. Here's what is happening:

1. Thin vm client powers on and gets assigned `192.168.9.20` by `LTSP server`
2. Thin client then is able to grab the pxelinux.0 file from `LTSP server`

   ```
   pxelinux.cfg/default       ok
   ```
3. Screen goes blank for a few moments
4. Then i get this error:

   ```
   Error: Socket failed: Connection timed out
   Exiting.
   ```

Thin client finally defaults into `BusyBox`.

Not sure if it matters, but, when I do an `ifconfig` from `(initramfs)` prompt, i see that the ip address is now `192.168.9.101` which is odd.

**Edit**

Kind of flailing around now, but, when I tried to `(initfamfs) wget ftp://192.168.9.10`, I get `wget: can't connect to remote host (192.168.9.10)` where `192.168.9.10` is the LTSP server.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some guidance on [LTSP IRC](http://www.ltsp.org/irc/) (special thanks to `alkisg`), I figured out the issue. Ultimately, it turned out that my `VirtualBox` `host-only` network was doing something weird. It didn't actually disable the virtual `dhcp` server when I unchecked the box.

### Force VirtualBox Manager to disabled `dhcp`

Some other people had the same issue: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32201

1. On your host machine, list the running dhcp servers: `VBoxManage list dhcpservers`
2. Note the name of the dhcp service you want to disable, then `VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --netname {name of dhcp server}`. In my case: `VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --netname HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1`
3. Do another `VBoxManage list dhcpservers` to ensure it's actually gone.

### Debugging steps

On the thin server, modify the pxe boot command issued to the thin client located in `/var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/{architecture}/pxelinux.cfg/default` where {architecture} is either `amd64` or `i386`. Although the config file says not to edit anything because your changes will be overwritten, it's fine to do so as we're just testing. You'll want to locate the correct section that pertains to your LTSP setup (whether `NBD` or `NFS`) and make it look something like the following n.b. the `break=mount`:

```
label ltsp-NBD
menu label LTSP, using NBD
kernel vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
# append ro initrd=initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic init=/sbin/init-ltsp quiet splash root=/dev/nbd0
append ro initrd=initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic init=/sbin/init-ltsp root=/dev/nbd0 break=mount
ipappend 2
```

1. First, from your LTSP server tail the log to see what errors come up: `tail /var/log/syslog -f`.
2. Now, reboot the thin client and you should be presented with an `(initramfs)` command prompt.
3. Check the ip address of your machine to make sure your on the correct network by running: `ifconfig`.
4. Check the network configuration provided by the LTSP server: `cat /run/net-eth0.cfg`. (For me, I noticed that the ip address assigned to `ROOTSERVER` was not the same as that of my LTSP server.)
5. Check to see if you can manually mount and boot the image from the LTSP server: `nbd-client {ltsp server ip} -N /opt/ltsp/{architecture} /dev/nbd0`.

As I said, ultimately, something funky was going on w/ my vm `host-only` network and after powering off the server and client and restarting, it all worked.

Hope this helps someone.